# geom_smooth with facet_grid and different fitting functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

First of all, apologies for the example, but I couldn't find a better data set to demonstrate the problem. Hopefully, it will suffice. Say I'm trying to make a facet grid of transmission (automatic vs. manual) and number of gears from the `mtcars` data set that plots mpg against displacement, like this:

```
# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Plot data
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(gear ~ am)
p <- p + geom_smooth()
print(p)
```

which gives,

[image]

Notice, I've added a trend line using `geom_smooth` and it has defaulted to use a loess curve. I can fit user-defined functions rather than a loess curve using  `nls` for the method and then stating a formula, which is great. But is it possible to fit **different** user-specified curves for each facet? For example, a linear regression to the top left panel and decaying exponential for the bottom right. Is this possible? Or am I using a hammer to drive in screws?

**EDIT**:
A solution for custom (i.e., user-defined) fitting functions is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930704/r-nls-not-picking-up-additional-arguments-when-used-in-custom-function-in-geom/44932146#44932146).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370648/modify-lm-or-loess-function-to-use-it-within-ggplot2s-geom-smooth), a possibile solution is:

```
# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Vector of smoothing methods for each plot panel
meths <- c("loess","lm","lm","lm","lm","lm","lm")

# Smoothing function with different behaviour in the different plot panels
mysmooth <- function(formula,data,...){
   meth <- eval(parse(text=meths[unique(data$PANEL)]))
   x <- match.call()
   x[[1]] <- meth
   eval.parent(x)
}

# Plot data
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(gear ~ am)
p <- p + geom_smooth(method="mysmooth")
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Marco. It's much appreciated. I notice that in `meths` you only use previously defined methods. Is this possible with user-defined methods, too? Could you provide an explanation of how `mysmooth` works, please? I'm guessing that `data$PANEL` is the facet number or ID? It looks like you're creating a command to execute on the first line (i.e., the method) and presumably this is executed in the final line, but how do the other two lines work?

Comment: Okay, so I think I'm getting there. `match.call()` gets all the arguments passed to the `mysmooth` function, then the first argument (i.e., `formula`) is replaced with our own formula, right? Next, the command is executed with this new formula. Is that correct?

Comment: How do you use different formulas for each facet? such as x~y and x~log(y)?