# R: nls not picking up additional arguments when used in custom function in geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

This is a question that relates to my earlier question [geom_smooth with facet_grid and different fitting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912496/geom-smooth-with-facet-grid-and-different-fitting-functions/44913300#44913300). In that question, I was trying to use a different fitting function in `geom_smooth` for each facet in a facet grid for ggplot2. [Marco Sandri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166684/marco-sandri) kindly provided an answer that I am trying to adapt to use user-defined formulas rather than existing formulas (e.g., `lm`, `loess`). Here is the my code.

```
# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Smoothing function with different behaviour depending on the panel
custom.smooth <- function(formula, data,...){
  smooth.call <- match.call()

  if(as.numeric(unique(data$PANEL)) == 6) {
    # Nonlinear regression
    method.name <- eval(parse(text="nls"))
    # Specify formula
    formula <- as.formula("y ~ a * x^b")
    # Add initial parameters
    smooth.call[["start"]] <- c(a = 10, b = -0.5)
  }else{
    # Linear regression
    method.name <- eval(parse(text="lm"))
  }

  # Add function name
  smooth.call[[1]] <- method.name
  # Perform fit
  eval.parent(smooth.call)
}

# Plot data with custom fitting function
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(gear ~ am)
p <- p + geom_smooth(method = "custom.smooth")
print(p)
```

In this code, I define a function `custom.smooth` that chooses the model to be fit. In this example, all models are linear regressions except for panel 6, which is a user-defined function `y ~ a*x^b`. Running this code gives the error:

> Warning message: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: singular
>   gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

Nevertheless, when I run `nls` on the data in panel 6 with these initial parameters I get no such error (i.e., `nls(mpg ~ a * disp^b, mtcars %>% filter(gear == 5, am == 1), start = c(a = 10, b = -0.5))`). This makes me think that `nls` isn't seeing the start values I specify. I have also tried specifying these parameters in the `geom_smooth` function like this:

```
p <- p + geom_smooth(method = "custom.smooth", method.args = list(start = c(a = 10, b = -0.5)))
```

but I run into the same issue. Any ideas how I can get my start values to `nls`? Or is there another reason why the code isn't working?

Comment: I don't think it is your starting values.  Not only does the model converge even when using the default starting values from `nls` (which will return a warning), it works fine to plot a `nls` line via `geom_smooth` to the gear 5 am 1 data without giving starting values.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't checked that. Hmmm. The linear fits work, so is it how I'm specifying the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution, which greatly benefited from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370648/modify-lm-or-loess-function-to-use-it-within-ggplot2s-geom-smooth). I don't know *why* the previous version didn't work, but this seems to work fine.

```
# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Smoothing function with different behaviour depending on the panel
custom.smooth <- function(formula, data,...){
  smooth.call <- match.call()

  if(as.numeric(unique(data$PANEL)) == 6) {
    # Nonlinear regression
    smooth.call[[1]] <- quote(nls)
    # Specify formula
    smooth.call$formula <- as.formula("y ~ a * x ^ b")
    # Add initial parameters
    smooth.call$start <- c(a = 300, b = -0.5)
  }else{
    # Linear regression
    smooth.call[[1]] <- quote(lm)
  }

  # Perform fit
  eval.parent(smooth.call)
}

# Plot data with custom fitting function
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(gear ~ am)
p <- p + geom_smooth(method = "custom.smooth", se = FALSE)
print(p)
```

Comment: The previous version didn't work because you didn't update the call with the new formula, you just created a variable called `formula` but then didn't do anything with it.

Comment: Ah. I thought the function was being passed a variable called `formula`, so all I needed to do was change it's value.

Comment: Your function helped me a lot, but now I have another question, maybe you already had a solution, please see this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381672/specifying-formula-for-each-facet-using-stat-poly-eq-in-ggplot2